# MaterialButtonToggleGroup child's MaterialButton layout_marginStart, layout_marginEnd not working

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, android-togglebutton

If i am trying to add margin with **layout_marginStart** or **layout_marginEnd** but there is no effect on UI. I am not sure why **layout_marginStart**, **layout_marginEnd** not working with  **MaterialButton** when i add them as the child of **MaterialButtonToggleGroup**

[image]

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
                            app:singleSelection="true">

                            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/twentY"
                                app:icon="@drawable/ic_directions_walk_black_24dp" />

                            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/ten_dp"

                                app:icon="@drawable/ic_directions_car_black_24dp" />

                            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/ten_dp"
                                app:icon="@drawable/ic_directions_bus_black_24dp" />
                        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After hours straggling, I finally found clean solution for this.
we can easily use `android:insetRight` or  `android:insetLeft` to add spacing to the Material buttons.

Here is a code sample of 10dp (5dp + 5dp) space between each button:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
  android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:insetRight="5dp"
    ... />

  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:insetRight="5dp"
    android:insetLeft="5dp"
    ... />

  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:insetLeft="5dp"
    ... />

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

Hope this helps you too :)

Comment: This did the job. Thanks

Comment: If someone uses orientation `vertical` then buttons gave auto spacing, to remove spaces between buttons use `android:insetBottom="0dp"` or `android:insetTop="0dp"`.

Answer (score 1):

> In order to cohesively group multiple buttons together,
>   MaterialButtonToggleGroup overrides the start and end margins of any
>   children added to this layout such that child buttons are placed
>   directly adjacent to one another.

Sorry, **layout_marginStart** and **layout_marginEnd** will not work here. Read official guideline about [**MaterialButtonToggleGroup**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButtonToggleGroup).

You can try with **`ToggleButton`**.

```
                  <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ToggleButton
                            android:id="@+id/tJava"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textOff="JAVA"
                            android:textOn="JAVA" />

                       <ToggleButton
                            android:id="@+id/tKotlin"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textOff="KOTLIN"
                            android:textOn="KOTLIN" />

                </LinearLayout>
```

Then Java class onCreate() section

```
    tJava=findViewById(R.id.tJava);
    tKotlin=findViewById(R.id.tKotlin);


    tJava.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeChecker);
    tKotlin.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeChecker);
```

Then `changeChecker` function outside of onCreate()

```
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener changeChecker = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                if (buttonView == tJava) {

                    tKotlin.setChecked(false);

                }
                if (buttonView == tKotlin) {

                    tJava.setChecked(false);

                }

        }
    };
```

Comment: The solution you have provided is not working as expected there should only one button active at a time but it's not happening if I am trying to put three toggle button into a radiogroup.@IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: @Black4Guy Solved this yet ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently (`1.2.0-beta01` and `1.3.0-alpha01`) you can't do it.
As pointed out by [@IntelliJ Amiya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61248656/2016562)'s answer:

> In order to cohesively group multiple buttons together, `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` **overrides the start and end margins** of any children added to this layout such that child buttons are placed directly adjacent to one another.

There is a workaround (**not** so nice, but it works):

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>

   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
       style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
       app:strokeColor="@color/as_background"
       app:strokeWidth="2dp"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       app:backgroundTint="@color/my_group_selector"
       ../>
```

Use a stroke in your `MaterialButton` with the same color of the activity background. The `strokeWidth` wokrs *like* a margin.
Finally use a selector with supports the checked state:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.30" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

[image]